# Second argument in .retrieve(); always running?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've been experimenting with Element storage, and I'm stumped by a problem with `.retrieve();` in Element Storage.

The documentation states:

> Element:retrieve actually accepts an optional second parameter which will act as the default value to store if another value doesn’t previously exist. It will then retrieve the value as expected.

Basic examples work, but when I am instantiating a [Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class) in the second parameter, that instantiation gets run every time, even though I can verify that `.retrieve();` is returning the `Class` object that was instantiated prior.

[Relevent jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7qFA/)

If you take a look at the fiddle, you can see that every time you click the div, myClass gets instantiated again. Ideally, it should be instantiated once, that object should be saved into Element storage, and retrieves properly in order to stop it from being instantiated again.

This is how I am calling `.retrieve();`:

```
$('baz').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.retrieve('foobar', new myClass()).foo();
});
```

... and just for fun, I tried this (it also didn't work):

```
$('baz').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.retrieve('foobar', (function() {
        return new myClass();
    })()).foo();
});
```

... and here is how I finally got it to work, by NOT using `.retrieve()`'s second parameter:

```
$('baz').addEvent('click', function() {
    var instClass = this.retrieve('foobar');
    if (instClass == null) {
        instClass = this.store('foobar', new myClass()).retrieve('foobar');
    }
    instClass.foo();
});
```

Any clue what's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument always *gets evaluated*, yes. In your case, a new instance of `myClass` is instantiated with every `retrieve` call - that's what you see in the console. This will always happen, regardless of the outcome of the call or whether the parameter is actually processed in the method (you could pass e.g. 10 more parameters to the method, they will all get evaluated at the moment of the call).

<strike>In your case, there is another misunderstanding: when the default parameter of the `retrieve` call is used, it won't be stored automatically. Therefore your third variant is actually the right solution to the task</strike>

> *Retrieve value for key 'foobar' – if no value has been set, create a new
>   instance of* `myClass`*, store it as 'foobar' and return it.*

(Updated - I was wrong with my second state statement, as @Julian H. Lam pointed out: the second parameter to `retrieve` is actually immediately stored.)

Comment: good catch, thought there was an error in the retrieve code for a moment :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - that's a little annoying, but understandable (I suppose). The write-up was written in a way that I misinterpreted it, and thought that when defined, the default value gets both passed back **and** stored into element storage. Unfortunate.

Comment: @Julian D., the more I read into it, the more it seems like it *should* store the value into element storage. Even the [example](http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/22/whats-new-in-12-element-storage/) given mentions it: `$('myElement').retrieve('defaultValue', 'Some Default Value'); //stores and returns 'Some Default Value' if the key doesn't previously exist`

Comment: I also remembered (before writing this question) to check if the class was being saved at all to the storage without being explicitly stored, and it was. If you modify my original fiddle and add `console.log(this.retrieve('foobar'));` right before `.retrieve();` gets called, it returns `null` on first click (as expected), and returns the `myClass` Object on all subsequent clicks. The class just gets re-instantiated for kicks, it seems like... unless I am misunderstanding something here, Mootools **is** storing the default value automatically.

Comment: It does work as prescribed. Only by having `new c()`, it will create a new instance every time as the () runs immediately. You can test by assigning the instance on the outside to a var and passing the var instead will work.

Comment: I was afraid of that - I was hoping that even if `new Class();` was passed in, it would only be run once, as the returned value would be saved in the storage, but it seems as though this is not the case. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you are absolutely right: the value is in fact stored and my statement was wrong. I've updated my answer.

Comment: BTW, if you want a one-liner for your required behaviour, you could use `this.retrieve('foobar', this.retrieve('foobar') || new myClass())`. Just for the fun of it, I am a big fan of descriptive code and therefore wouldn't really recommend shortcuts like this one.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as expected, unfortunately - as @Julian D. pointed out, it will always run the `new myClass()`

An alternative pattern is quite popular in mootools, used by element.tween / morph and so forth, that looks like this:

```
var myClass = new Class({

    Implements: [Options],

    options: {
        foo: "bar"
    },

    initialize: function(element, options) {
        console.log('I have been initialized!');
        this.setOptions(options);
    },
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this.options.foo);
    }
});

Element.Properties.myClass = {

    set: function(options){
        this.get('myClass').setOptions(options);
        return this;
    },

    get: function(){
        var instance = this.retrieve('myClass');
        if (!instance){
            instance = new myClass(this);
            this.store('myClass', instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }

};


$('baz').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.get('myClass').foo();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/R7qFA/2/

The getter - when run - will return the instance from storage for you, if available, else, it will make one for you and store it, then return it.

To create an instance with custom options, use `element.set("myClass", { options }`.

You can even use this in a new Element constructor like so:

```
new Element("a", {
    myClass: {
        foo: "no bars for you"
    }
});
```

The above will create an instance of myClass and make it available to the element with the foo property being custom.

Here is an example in real life where I use it: 
https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mootstrap-button/blob/master/Source/mootstrap-button.js

and check documentation/example here:
https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mootstrap-button/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
(function() {
  var def = new myClass();
  $('baz').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.retrieve('foobar', def).foo();
  });
}());
```

This way the event function has the instance already instantiated so at execution will not create new ones.